# Missing Macintosh HD after erasing MacBook computer

Tags: macbook-pro

In the process of erasing my computer, I can no longer see Macintosh HD. I did use the security option to do a thorough erase. When I try to reinstall operating system, only OS X Base System shows up. What can I do ?

Comment: Have you tried executing [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) by holding down Command - R?

Comment: Yes, and when I go to reinstall the only drive that shows up is OS X Base System.  If I select it, I get the message it is locked.

Comment: I also want to mention, I used to manage a Unix computer, and I'm familiar with using unix commands.  Just don't know what the unix command would be to recreate the partition so I can install the system.

Comment: What model of Mac is this? Is it a hard drive or SSD? If the device is not even showing in Recovery's Disk Utility, that might suggest that it has failed. (Multiple zeros across the entire volume can be the straw that breaks an elderly camel's back.)

Comment: It is Model A1226 purchased in 2007.  I'm able to get to the Recovery's Disk Utility.

Comment: You have to reinitialize the drive in Disk Utility.  If you have the original install disk, go to Tools in the menu bar, go v into Disk Utility and partition and format the drive. Once you do that, you can install macOS

Comment: Thanks Allan.  I do not have the install disk.  When I boot up to get the disk utility and try to make a partition, it tells me the volume is not journaled.  I think I'll have to wait for the Genius Bar to open again.

Comment: Allan, you got me going in the right direction.  I did find my original install disks, and am in the process of re-installing the system.  Hopefully this will rebuild the partitions correctly.  So far it is looking good.  Thank you.